# sequelize-cli: running single seed file is slow

Tags: sequelize.js

When I run all the seeds with `sequelize-cli db:seed:all` the command will finish running in under a second. However, if I try to run a single seed file with `sequelize-cli db:seed --seed {file}` it'll take about 10 seconds to run.  The terminal output shows me that the seed finishes "migrating" in under .5 seconds but it then just hangs for the other 9.5 seconds. Any ideas on how to fix/debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a very interesting param in `options.pool.idle` which is 10000ms by default. Please play around with it, because it keeps the connection for 10s by default.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

[Sequelize - Public Constructors](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)